# Averaging nearby points in an array

Tags: c#

The following code takes in an point array and removes all of the nearby points whilst averaging them based on the conditions past in.

The variable `_nCornerTolerance` is an int that is calculated prior in the class. Typically it is around 5;

```
private Point[] AverageNearbyPoints(Point[] points, bool averageLeft, bool averageHigh)
{
    List<Point> plAveragedPoints = new List<Point>();
    for (int pi = 0, pc = points.Length; pi < pc; ++pi)
    {
        Point[] paNearbyPoints = points.Where(p => (Math.Abs(p.X - points[pi].X) <= _nCornerTolerance)
                                                && (Math.Abs(p.Y - points[pi].Y) <= _nCornerTolerance))
                                        .ToArray();
        if (paNearbyPoints.Length > 1)
        {
            int nX = averageLeft ? (int)Math.Floor(paNearbyPoints.Sum(p => p.X) / (float)paNearbyPoints.Length)
                                    : (int)Math.Ceiling(paNearbyPoints.Sum(p => p.X) / (float)paNearbyPoints.Length);

            int nY = averageHigh ? (int)Math.Floor(paNearbyPoints.Sum(p => p.Y) / (float)paNearbyPoints.Length)
                                    : (int)Math.Ceiling(paNearbyPoints.Sum(p => p.Y) / (float)paNearbyPoints.Length);

            if (!plAveragedPoints.Any(p => p.X == nX && p.Y == nY))
            {
                plAveragedPoints.Add(new Point(nX, nY));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!plAveragedPoints.Any(p => p.X == points[pi].X && p.Y == points[pi].Y))
            {
                plAveragedPoints.Add(points[pi]);
            }
        }
    }

    return plAveragedPoints.ToArray();
}
```

Is there anyway I can rewrite the `int nX = ...` and `int nY = ...` parts better so I don't need the conditional?

A full review of this code would also be helpful, although the main part I am asking about is the above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Naming

- plAveragedPoints
- paNearbyPoints

this variables would be more obvious if you wouldn't use this strange kind of hungarian notation. I figured out the `pl` means point list and `pa` point array, but if you need to read this fast you just can't because your brain will try to decypher what `pl` and `pa` means.

Does it really matter wether it is a `List` or an `Array` ?

---

> ```
>        if (!plAveragedPoints.Any(p => p.X == nX && p.Y == nY))
>         {
>             plAveragedPoints.Add(new Point(nX, nY));
>         }
> ```

and

> ```
>        if (!plAveragedPoints.Any(p => p.X == points[pi].X && p.Y == points[pi].Y))
>         {
>             plAveragedPoints.Add(points[pi]);
>         }
> ```

made me think that maybe a `HashSet<Point>` would be the better datastructure instead of a `List<Point`. You could simply call the `Add()` method and forget about the result of it.

---

Instead of using the tenary expression, @Caridoc had shown a different implementation which was a good start.

I would suggest to add another method which takes two `Func<double,double>` which are determined before calling that overloaded method like so

```
    private Func<double, double> CreateDesiredFunc(bool useFloor)
    {
        if (useFloor)
        {
            return Math.Floor;
        }
        return Math.Ceiling;
    }
```

Edit: Like @RickDavin pointed out in the comments this can be cleaned a little bit more by using more idiomatic names for the looping index variable and for the coordinate variables. In addition you should/could use the `var` type where it is clear from the right hand side of an assignment what type it is.

This boils down to the following

```
    private Point[] AverageNearbyPoints(Point[] points, bool averageLeft, bool averageHigh)
    {
        return AverageNearbyPoints(points, CreateDesiredFunc(averageLeft), CreateDesiredFunc(averageHigh));
    }

    private Point[] AverageNearbyPoints(Point[] points, Func<double, double> averageLeft, Func<double, double> averageHigh)
    {
        var averagedPoints = new HashSet<Point>();
        int numberOfPoints = points.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints ; ++i)
        {
            var nearbyPoints = points.Where(p => (Math.Abs(p.X - points[i].X) <= _nCornerTolerance)
                                              && (Math.Abs(p.Y - points[i].Y) <= _nCornerTolerance))
                                            .ToArray();
            var point = points[pi];

            if (nearbyPoints.Length > 1)
            {
                int x = (int)averageLeft(nearbyPoints.Sum(p => p.X) / (float)nearbyPoints.Length);

                int y = (int)averageHigh(nearbyPoints.Sum(p => p.Y) / (float)nearbyPoints.Length);

                point = new Point(x, y);

            }

            averagedPoints.Add(point);
        }

        return averagedPoints.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Very helpful, the naming convention is something from my workplace so I am stuck with it. Once you get used to it, it is easier to tell what a data structure is when you can't see where it is initialised